# JS,Jquery vertical scroll of divs and li on up/down buttons-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vertical-scrolling

I have two lists - one with divs and one with li elements that I need to vertcal-scroll on p and down buttons click.
The problem is that it is not very presice for li and has glitches in browsers like IE...
Is there a way to improve it?

```
    <div class="selectOpt">
         <div><img class="topScroll" src="arrowup.png" title="Up"></img></div>
         <div class="list"><ul class="choose"></ul></div>
         <div><img class="bottomScroll" src="arrowdown.png" title="Down"></img></div>
    </div>
```

I fill it with:

```
$(".choose").append('<li class="'+list[i]+'Item" value="'+item[1]+'">'+item[1]+'</li>');
```

And I use this code to scroll it:

```
 $(function scrollDivs(){ $('.topScroll').on('click', function(){
            var element = $(this).parents('.selectOpt').children('.list').children('ul');
            if (parseInt(element.css('top')) <= -20){
                element.css('top', "+="+ parseInt(element.children('li').css('height').replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "")*2.1).toString()+"px").css({'transition': 'all 0.4s ease-out'                    });
            } //else $('.topScroll').css('opacity', '0.3');
        });
        $('.bottomScroll').on('click', function() {
            var element = $(this).parents('.selectOpt').children('.list').children('ul');
            if ( parseInt(element.css('top')) >= (parseInt(element.parent().css('height')) - parseInt(element.css('height'))) ){
                element.css('top', "-="+ parseInt(element.children('li').css('height').replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "")*2.09).toString()+"px").css({'transition': 'all 0.4s ease-out'});
            } //else $('.bottomScroll').css('opacity', '0.3');
        });
    });
```

And there is a div with divs to scroll:

```
<div class="schedule"></div>
```

I fill it with:
..

```
.forEach(function(raw){
$('.schedule").append('<div class="eRaw"><span class="pe"></span><span class="time"></span><span class="date"></span></div>');});
```

I scroll divs with:

```
var step=10;
var scrolling=false;
$(".scrollUp").bind("click",function(event) {event.preventDefault();
    $(".schedule").animate({scrollTop: "-=" +step+ "px"});
}).bind("mousedown",function(event) {scrolling=true;scrollContent("up");
}).bind("mouseup",function(event) {scrolling=false;});
$(".scrollDown").bind("click",function(event) {event.preventDefault();
    $(".schedule").animate({scrollTop: "+=" +step+ "px"});
}).bind("mousedown",function(event) {scrolling=true;scrollContent("down");
}).bind("mouseup",function(event) {scrolling=false;});
function scrollContent(direction) {var amount = (direction === "up" ? "-=1px" : "+=1px");
    $(".schedule").animate({scrollTop:amount}, 1, function(){if(scrolling){scrollContent(direction);}});
}
$(".schedule").on('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting different scroll amounts with different browsers, perhaps doing a css reset can help if you aren't already.

Different browsers can add varying amounts of padding and margins to elements, but if everything is equal then the effect should be the same in all browsers.

For every project I always have in the top of my main css file:

CSS:

```
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,
abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,
strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,dd,dl,dt,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,
tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 100%;
line-height: 1.2;
font-family: inherit;
text-align: left;
}
```

Note, this might change how some other elements look if you don't already do this because there might be some compensation in your code, but is definitely worth the equality